# PyQGIS: How to store the result of cliprasterbymasklayer

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

This Question is a follow up Question to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343692/adding-layer-from-cliprasterbymask-using-pyqgis) I recently asked.

In my plugin I have a function that clips rasters by mask and I would like that the function returns the raster layer object. And then in another function I can get the Object. That's the code so far:

```
def clipRaster(self):
    wasserstand = self.getRasterLayer()
    outFile = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "rtemp.tiff")
    gebeude = self.getVectorLayer()
    clip = processing.run('gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer',{'INPUT': wasserstand,'MASK': gebeude,
                   'NODATA': -1, 'ALPHA_BAND': False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True, 'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
                   'OPTIONS': "", 'DATA_TYPE': 5, 'OUTPUT': outFile})

    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(clip['OUTPUT'])

    #rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(path_to_tif, "SRTM layer name")

    return rlayer

def getclip(self):
    clip = self.clipRaster()

    self.iface.addRasterLayer(clip)

    #iface.addRasterLayer("/path/to/raster/file.tif", "layer name you like")
```

Unfortunately, the error message I get is the following:

> TypeError QgisInterface.addRasterLayer() arguments did not match any overloaded call   overload 1 argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'   overload 2 argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'

Why isn't it working? "outFile" defines the path and name of the raster, the processing algorithm creates a raster layer and puts it into the "outFile" directory. To create a new raster the function QgsRasterLayer() needs a path and layer name which is both in outFile, thus the raster is now saved in the rlayer variable. Finally, iface.addRasterLayer(clip) adds this object. It makes sense doesn't it? :).

Can someone explain my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you recall from your previous question, the method `iface.addRasterLayer()` takes 2 string arguments- the file path and layer name as parameters. You are passing it a raster layer object, hence the error is telling you that argument 1 has the unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'.

You can use the `addMapLayer()` method which belongs to the `QgsProject` class instead. You can pass this method the raster layer object returned by your `clipRaster()` function.

```
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(clip)
```

Since this is in a plugin you will have to add `QgsProject` to your `qgis.core` imports.

By the way, I would recommend giving your raster layer a name when you create it:

```
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(clip['OUTPUT'], 'Wasserstand_clipped') # call it whatever you want
```

After all, do you really want an un-named raster layer in the table of contents panel?